# Flurl \ RestSharp: `\r\n` is added to each parameter of the Multipart request

Tags: asp.net-core, multipartform-data, restsharp, flurl, freshdesk

I'm trying to write a call to the Freshdesk API using either Flurl or RestSharp library.

The API call I'm trying to write is Creating a Ticket: https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#create_ticket

An example of cURL:

`curl -v -u yourapikey:X -F "attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment1.ext" -F "attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment2.ext" -F "email=example@example.com" -F "subject=Ticket Title" -F "description=this is a sample ticket" -X POST 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'`

Note params are passed by `-F` (i.e. `--form`) flag.

With the following code calling Flurl:

```cs
var rs = await url.WithBasicAuth(_configuration.ApiKey, _configuration.Password)
                  .PostMultipartAsync(mp =>
                  {
                      mp.AddString("email", ticket.Email);
                      mp.AddString("subject", ticket.Subject);
                      mp.AddString("status", ticket.Status.ToString());
                      mp.AddString("priority", ticket.Priority.ToString());
                      mp.AddString("description", ticket.Description);
                  });
```

...Or the following code calling RestSharp:

```cs
var request = new RestRequest("tickets", Method.Post);
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddParameter("email", ticket.Email);
request.AddParameter("description", ticket.Description);
request.AddParameter("subject", ticket.Subject);
request.AddParameter("status", ticket.Status);
request.AddParameter("priority", ticket.Priority);

var rs = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

...I'm receiving 400 BadRequest with the following information (in both cases):

```json
{
    "description": "Validation failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "invalid_field",
            "field": "email\r\n",
            "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request"
        },
        {
            "code": "invalid_field",
            "field": "subject\r\n",
            "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request"
        },
        {
            "code": "invalid_field",
            "field": "status\r\n",
            "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request"
        },
        {
            "code": "invalid_field",
            "field": "priority\r\n",
            "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request"
        },
        {
            "code": "invalid_field",
            "field": "description\r\n",
            "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that:

- Freshdesk API uses `-F` / `--form` as a way to pass parameters.
- I want to use Multipart for handling attachments later on.
- All data has proper values. If it wouldn't have a proper value, a validation error would come as a response.
- When sending the same values in Postman (via form-data), I'm receiving 201 Created.

## Update 1

Postman screenshot (working example):

[image]

## Update 2

I tried to use Tiny.RestClient which has cURL listener and it came with the following cURL generated:

```
curl -X POST [...] -d "--1c3acb07-77bd-494d-bc56-21290dcd5088
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=email

a@a.com
[...]
```

Perhaps, Flurl and RestSharp uses the same way to proceed with parameters and thus, the `\r\n` in fields.

Comment: .NET doesn't append newlines to fields and I doubt flurl does either. Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to capture and inspect the actual request and response. Flurl uses .NET Core's HttpClient and HttpClientFactory, which means you can use the .NET Core logs generated by HttpClient to see what Flurl sends.

Comment: A screenshot of it working in Postman could be helpful.

Comment: @ToddMenier: Added Postman screenshot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: One thing that comes to my mind is that both RestSharp and Flurl can use the `-d` flag for passing multipart params (see the similar question for Tiny.RestClient: https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient/issues/120). I'm going to inspect the logs, thank you for your tips.

Comment: I'm stumped. Hopefully comparing the raw log to the raw Postman request will reveal the issue. All I can confirm is that Flurl does not add CRLF to field names so I believe that's some quirk with the FD error response. (Once you can prove this I would suggest editing your question title, which I believe is misleading as it stands.)

Comment: @ToddMenier: Yes, that's weird. What's your recommendation to see what is being sent via Flurl? Also, have you seen Update 2 of the question? Maybe that's the source of new lines interpreted wrong by Freshdesk API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the FreshDesk API issue. They want, for some reason, for multipart form-data parameter names to be enclosed in quotation marks. It's not a requirement per HTTP standards. RestSharp and Flurl use `MultipartFormDataContent`, and it  adds uses parameter names as provided.

Following up on your issue, I added this property to `RestRequest`:

```
/// <summary>
/// When set to true, parameters in a multipart form data requests will be enclosed in
/// quotation marks. Default is false. Enable it if the remote endpoint requires parameters
/// to be in quotes (for example, FreshDesk API). 
/// </summary>
public bool MultipartFormQuoteParameters { get; set; }
```

It is available in RS 107.3.0.

You can also make it work by adding parameters like this:

```
request.AddParameter("\"status\"", ticket.Status);
```

Comment: i was struggking with the freshdesk api using RestSharp untill i came across your answer added quotation marks and done. Thanks man!